# Amazon S3 - Token Vending Machines/IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, tvm

I have the following policy configured in a IAM user and in one TVM because I need acces from S3 in an Android app but, whenever I try to save my credentials i get the same "500 - Server error". I dont have idea about the problem but i guess that the policy is bad configured:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:GetFederationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetUser",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There are 2 policies.  Did you restrict the policy that the TVM uses for generating temporary credentials?  The file is src/TokenVendingMachinePolicy.json.  Not restricting this file will result in a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, I have this same policy in both. Is that a problem?

Comment: You'll want to restrict the actual TVM policy to only those actions necessary in your mobile app.  Leaving in the STS, IAM and SimpleDB permissions would potentially allow the mobile app to modify the TVM table.

Comment: Thanks! How could limit the use of DB to allow the TVM function but not the other operations?
Currently I have the following policy:                                 {
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:GetFederationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetUser",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "sdb:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}]
}

Comment: Either simply don't add the statements for iam and sdb in the TokenVendingMachinePolicy.json or do as the example policy does and deny the operations: {"Statement":
    [
        {"Effect":"Allow","Action":["s3:*", "sdb:*", "sqs:*", "sns:*", "dynamodb:*"],"Resource":"*"},
        {"Effect":"Deny","Action":"sdb:*","Resource":["arn:aws:sdb:__REGION__:__ACCOUNT_ID__:domain/__USERS_DOMAIN__","arn:aws:sdb:__REGION__:__ACCOUNT_ID__:domain/__DEVICE_DOMAIN__"]},
        {"Effect":"Deny","Action":"iam:*","Resource":"*"}
    ]
}

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" to your question title, or add the answer into your question. Answers go in the _Answers_ section. And I have already edited out "solved" from your title once. Don't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclamer: this answer was moved from the question to a community wiki here.*

---

Solution: The problem was that I also needed to add permissions for sdb, where the credentials are stored.